# inserting to database from query in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table of tweet data *my_tweets* containing these columns: *tweet_id*, *text*, *created_at*, *sentiment*

My tweet data is being streamed live and simultaneously inserted into the table.
I am writing code using Vader to get the sentiment of the text.
At the moment, *tweet_id*, *text*, and *created_at* are all populated.

I would like to use this query: `SELECT * FROM my_tweets WHERE sentiment is null` in MySQL to get rows where *sentiment* is null and insert the sentiment from Vader.

Any suggestions on how I can go about this?

My program currently looks like this:

```
getTweetSentiment():
   #my code
   return score

addSentimentToDatabase():
   try:
      con = mysql.connector.connect(host = h, database = db, user = un, password = pw)
      query = ("SELECT * FROM my_tweets WHERE sentiment is null")
      #need to insert sentiment based on what the query returns
   except error as e:
      print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you put it this cannot be done in one go, you would have to use several steps.

1. **Save the data in a DataFrame**: Return the results, because you are doing a data science related application and AI I recommend you to use `pd.read_sql` ([the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)) from Pandas to pass the result to a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

con = mysql.connector.connect(host = h, database = db, user = un, password = pw)
query = ("SELECT * FROM my_tweets WHERE sentiment is null")
df_query = pd.read_sql(query,con)
```

2. Perform the operations you make with the data.
3. **Insert the results**. I recommend you to do it in a different def so that the quality and readability of your code is better. [This documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) explains how to make these insertions.

I hope I have helped you!